# Can $(A \lor B) \land (\lnot A \land \lnot C)$ be more simplified?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Can $(A \lor B) \land (\lnot A \land \lnot C)$ be more simplified/expanded? With a kind of distributive property?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\begin{align} (A\lor B)\land (\lnot A \land \lnot C) & \equiv  [(A\lor B) \land \lnot A] \land \lnot C \\ \\
& \equiv [\underbrace{(A\land \lnot A)}_{\text{False}}\lor (\lnot A \land B)] \land \lnot C \\ \\
& \equiv \lnot A \land B \land \lnot C
\end{align}$$

The first equivalence is simply due to the associativity of $\land$.

The second is by use of the distributive property, distributing a conjunct over a disjunction.

Third, we have $F\lor P\equiv P$.

Answer (score 1):

$(A \lor B) \land (\lnot A \land \lnot C) \longleftrightarrow (A \land \lnot A \land \lnot C) \lor (B \land \lnot A \land \lnot C) \longleftrightarrow False \lor (B \land \lnot A \land \lnot C) \longleftrightarrow B \land \lnot A \land \lnot C$

Answer (score 1):

We can "dsitribute" the OR in $(A \vee B) \wedge (\neg A \wedge \neg C)$ to get
$[A \wedge (\neg A \wedge \neg C)] \vee [B \wedge (\neg A \wedge \neg C)]$

One of the terms should seem supicious.

Answer (score 1):

$
\newcommand{\calc}{\begin{align} \quad &}
\newcommand{\calcop}[2]{\\ #1 \quad & \quad \unicode{x201c}\text{#2}\unicode{x201d} \\ \quad & }
\newcommand{\endcalc}{\end{align}}
\newcommand{\ref}[1]{\text{(#1)}}
\newcommand{\iff}{\equiv}
\newcommand{\true}{\text{true}}
\newcommand{\false}{\text{false}}
$One law of logic that is not very well known, but very useful in cases like this one, is
$$
\tag 0 P \land E(P) \;\iff\; P \land E(\true)
$$
("assume one side of $\;\land\;$ is $\;\true\;$ on the other side") together with its dual
$$
\tag 1 P \lor E(P) \;\iff\; P \lor E(\false)
$$
where $\;E(P)\;$ is any boolean expression which contains $\;P\;$ as a free variable.

This allows us to do the simplification even more quickly than in the earlier answers:

$$\calc
(A \lor B) \land \lnot A \land \lnot C
\calcop\iff{by $\ref 0$: assume $\;\lnot A\;$ is $\;\true\;$ on the left hand side of the first $\;\land\;$}
(\false \lor B) \land \lnot A \land \lnot C
\calcop\iff{simplify: $\;\false\;$ is the identity of $\;\lor\;$}
B \land \lnot A \land \lnot C
\endcalc$$

Of course, to *prove* $\ref 0$ and $\ref 1$ you still would need to use distribution and contradiction as in the older answers, together with induction over the structure of boolean expressions...  But when you're *using* logic in calculations, then these generalized laws often come in very useful.